# making a directory from the servlet in project's web folder

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish, mkdir

I have to make a folder from a servlet in the project's *web* directory. *(Like: web/Users/userinform)* To do that i make a call to the helper class that works to make a directory but it is unable to make one. Even if i invoke `mkdir` from within the servlet then also directory is not made. *(returns false)*  What is the reason ? How can i do so ?

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: Can you post the code what you have tried ?

Comment: @Srikanth Venkatesh `new File("web/Users/me@this.com").mkdir()` : CODE. I have to make `me@this.com` directory. Users directory is already there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
 new File(request.getRealPath("users") + "/me@this.com").mkdir();
```

Never you should rely to modify in deployed web application.

Refer this [modify properties file in Tomcat during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350974/modify-properties-file-in-tomcat-during-runtime)

Comment: Able to create the dir when using SpringSource Tool Suite 
Version: 2.8.1. with tomcat.Will let you know what can be done in netbeans.

Comment: It returns true when i make directory using the code u gave. but i can't find the directory in users ! what could be the reason

Comment: Netbeans may be any temporary directory to deploy the web app.Check for the location where the app is deployed.

Comment: the new directory is created in the `project/build/web/Users/` path. I want it in the `project/web/Users/` path.  See the edit. I want to create a directory in the **Users** directory shown in the pic

Answer (score 0):

First, maybe you need to use the "mkdirs()" flavor of the call, ensuring all parents are created also.

Second, where do you assume your directory to be created: as a child of the web application deplyoment path? Then answer of @Srikanth should work - recheck.

If you try to write outside this path, you should double check the file system permissions (not yours, but the user that is finally running the glassfish).

Comment: the directory is created in the `project/build/web/Users/` path. I want it in the `project/web/Users/` path

Comment: see the edit. I want to create a directory in the **Users** directory shown in the pic

Comment: Well, i don't know your specific IDE - assume its netbeans. It seems that the builtin servlet container simply works on the build output of your project "../build"..", not the project itself. Which is a good idea, by the way... So this is quite correct. Why do you want it otherwise?